# Listen on 9100 for print

Tags: java, sockets, printing, port

How can i listen to raw printer port 9100 in Java.

When i create ServerSocket on port 9100 and accept connection nothing happens when i try to print to this port.

```
System.out.println("listening on 9100");
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9100);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
        serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted connection");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: "Accepted connection" is never printed. So the socket is never initiated

Comment: What is supposed to happen, what happens (are those messages printed?)

Comment: sorry, nope the Accept is not printed. I've edited the question

Comment: If you have no exception that would mean that nothing reaches your server. Accept will fire once a connection on the specified port is opened. I.e. the error is probably on the other side (or some firewall blocking connections before they reach your code).

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the return value from `serverSocket.accept()`.
This gives you back a socket. Seems you're not using it at all.

[ServerSocket.accept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)

From that socket you then need to get input/output streams,
and then you can communicate with the client over these streams.

Comment: sorry, i did not tell that the socket is never accepted and the "Accepted connection is never printed"